# Dataframe won't return attribute accessed by list

Tags: r

I'm having an extremely perplexing problem and haven't been able to find the solution. I’m pasting my console output so that you can hopefully follow the issue, but the basic gist is that when I try to access a data frame attribute with a string, it has no problem, but if I replace that string with what should also be a string returned by a list access, it fails. I check to make sure “AA” and airline_names[1] have the same type, and they do (i and j are simply 1 and 1). It's likely something very basic, but I can't for the life of me figure it out.

```
> airline_names
[1] "AA" "AS" "B6" "DL" "EV" "F9" "FL" "HA" "MQ" "OO" "UA" "US" "VX" "WN" "YV"
> airline_names[1]
[1] "AA"
> typeof(airline_names[1])
[1] "character"
> typeof("AA")
[1] "character"
> airline_data[i]$"AA"$cancelled[j]
[1] 0
> airline_data[i]$airline_names[1]$cancelled[j]
NULL
> class("AA")
[1] "character"
> class(airline_names[1])
[1] "character"
```

`airline_data` is a list of dataframes. `airline_names` is a list of characters. `cancelled` is either 0 or 1.

Comment: Try `airline_data[i][[airline_names[1]]]$cancelled[j]`. You can't use `$` like this.

Comment: Ahh thank you so much! I haven't been around R enough it seems. If I might ask, what's the underlying reason for that?

Comment: `$` is basically a convenience function that is intended for interactive use. It uses non-standard evaluation, i.e., more typical use would be `airline_data[i]$AA$cancelled[j]`. Study `help("$")`.

Comment: Please don't write code like this. dplyr package will allow you to do `airline_data %>% filter(airline == 'AA') %>% summarize(cancelled)` or whatever you want